# Can't identify int in startActivityForResult?

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult

package com.example.feelhut;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;




public class editprofile extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton proileimagebutton;
    private static final int ImageRequest=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    proileimagebutton= findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
    proileimagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("imageeeeeee/");
```

There ImageRequest showing Error in startActivityForResult. Means I am not able to identify image request here.

```
startActivityForResult(intent.ImageRequest);

        }
    });
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class editprofile extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton proileimagebutton;
    private static final int ImageRequest=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //no content view? add like this setContentView(R.layout.yourViewLayout);
        proileimagebutton= findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        proileimagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,ImageRequest);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ImageRequest&& resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // your ImageView.setUri(data.getData();      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare int above "public class editprofile extends AppCompatActivity".
The code should be

```
private ImageButton proileimagebutton;


private static final int ImageRequest=1;
```

public class editprofile extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
proileimagebutton= findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
proileimagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("imageeeeeee/");
```